# Graph API update user.preferredLanguage not working because of insufficient privileges

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update the preferred language of a user using the /me endpoint or the /users/{currentUserID} endpoint but this always throws:

403 "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

[image]
[image]

I have checked the permissions according to the [documentation page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) and added the permissions for ***User.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All***. This does not seem to have any effect. Is the documentation incorrect or are there still permissions missing?

The request works fine if I execute it with an azure ad administrator user.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT: 2019-04-18**

I did some more testing:

1. I have created a new demo tenant using https://demos.microsoft.com
2. I logged in graph explorer with the tenant admin account  and gave admin consent for User.ReadWrite (and other default permissions asked by graph explorer).
3. I logged in with the Demo User.
4. I set the **preferredlanguage** to "en-US" using patch on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/. **This was successful**.
5. I tried to change the language again to "de-DE". **This did not work**:

*"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d1d30483-a3da-4775-af5b-4a3dd9823f11",
            "date": "2019-04-18T07:40:27"
        }*

Therefore it seems to work when setting the language for the first time. But updating it afterwards is impossible.

Comment: When did you add those permissions? When you add the permissions, try to logout and login again, close the browser and all that stuff... and try again logging back. you can also check the json web token permissions decoding the token (for example https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/).

Comment: I closed the browser and started in private mode afterwards. Did not help.

Comment: The token looks fine:
"scp": "... Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All Mail.ReadWrite MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All openid People.Read profile Reports.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All email",

Comment: Well, then I dont know :( at least at the moment... maybe is a bug and is another permission...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this issue:
I did some testing with Microsoft Support. For some reason updating **preferredLanguage** is only possible when the app has **Directory.AccessAsUser.All**.

Quite a heavy permission for just updating the user language...

Answer (score 0):

Neither documentation issue nor Graph permission missing. You need to check the [permission](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) in your azure AD but not just the Graph Exploer. My test based on two account(one MS account and one trial account which is test@xx.onmicrosoft). The trial one works well while the MS account cannot.

> Within organizations, the privileges of the signed-in user may be
>   determined by **policy or by membership** in one or more administrator
>   roles. For more information about administrator roles, see [Assigning
>   administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles).

Based on the test the documentation, not all users can change all profile data, some data have limitation by organization policy which cannot be ignore by the Grape Scopes settings.

For worked case, **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** is not essential

Comment: But the question is not about updating the language of every other user but only of the current one. There is no administrator role necessary for updating your own properties.

The article in your first hyperlink even says:

For example, assume your app has been granted the User.ReadWrite.All delegated permission. [...] **However, if the signed-in user is not in an administrator role, your app will be able to update only the profile of the signed-in user.**

Edit: Your second hyperlink is not working.

Comment: I am not agree with you. Many company have security policy, end user cannot modity their own user profile except phone. Other information are controlled by the HR/Admin(Many big company follow this rule). The second hyperlink have fixed. So even user signed-in, it do not mean user can modify profile.

Comment: Some docs based on ideal environment, if there are some group policy on the ad(or aad), signed-in non-admin user cannot change many information which belong to their own. This make sense for information security.

Comment: But this tenant is a development tenant. There are no company rules or anything to restrict setting user properties.

Furthermore the user can change the language in O365 "My Account" > "Settings"

Comment: Based on test result for dev tenant and actual company account, the result from me is to check AD setting again. If you are sure your ad setting is OK, i think you can report this as issue/bug in Github. The API itself should be OK.  "Furthermore the user can change the language in O365 "My Account" > "Settings", the operation support on UI may be not support on Graph API too.